# How to find the coordinates of point?

Tags: line, point

I have finite set of points in simple 2-dimensional Euclidean space ( I know coordinates of these points).

Let's say I pick point A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2) in 2-dimensional Euclidean space. So I have a line AB. I need to find coordinates of such point C  (actually I need to find if point C is in my set of points) , that length of AB = AC and lines AB and AC form right angle. (Actually two points should satisfy these conditions: on one side of the line AB and on other side)

This should be done in constant time.

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag it as such.

Comment: What have you tried? At the moment, this reads like a brief my boss would give me, rather than a request for help solving a problem.

Comment: Hbcdev, I tried using the fact that a*b = 0 if vectors a and b form right angle, also using slopes, but it was too complicated and I had a strong feeling that there is a simple solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You basically just want to rotate point B around point A by 90 degrees, right? If so, then first you translate A to the origin, then rotate, then translate back.

```
C = [-(y2-y1)+x1,x2-x1+y1]; // rotate +90 deg
C = [y2-y1+x1,-(x2-x1)+y1]; // rotate -90 deg
```